# Query from ejabberd module with LIKE %%

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I have this lines of code in ejabberd module, it works fine:

```
case catch ejabberd_odbc:sql_query(Server,["select COUNT(*) as total from spool where username='",IdUsername,"' AND xml LIKE '%message from%' AND xml LIKE '%chat%';"]) of
            {selected, [<<"total">>], [[Totale]]} ->
                Count = binary_to_list(Totale);
            _ -> Count = "0"
    end,
```

If I convert this:

```
LIKE '%chat%';
```

with this:

```
LIKE '%type=\'chat\'%';
```

I obtain an error, any ideas? or there's another way to get only the chat message?

Comment: no visible error, i obtain always 0, but from phpMyAdmin the same query give me three records! i think the problem is \'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're typing this in an Erlang string, the Erlang [escape sequences](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id75962) apply.  In particular, `\'` is an escape sequence for just a single quote, `'`.  (That's more useful inside atoms, which are delimited by single quotes.)

You can try it in an Erlang shell, and see that `"\'"` and `"'"` are equivalent:

```
1> "\'".
"'"
2> "\'" =:= "'".
true
```

To include an actual backslash in the string, escape it with another backslash:

```
"\\'"
```

In your case, that would be:

```
LIKE '%type=\\'chat\\'%';
```